# Stacking the bars based on attribute variable after equal.count function

Tags: r, lattice, shingles

I have got three variables; employee, PM and site in my table sitereview. Imported data to R.

```
 sitereview<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
```

[Sample data pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDGAb.jpg)

Classified data into 6 equal intervals using `equal.count` function from `library(lattice)`.

```
 equcount<-equal.count(sitereview$PM,6,0.05)
```

Plotted this to get the following table.

```
plot(equcount)
```

[Distribution of PM based on intervals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDGAb.jpg)

However, i want these bars to be stacked based on site wise. SOmething like the following pic. Anyway to include attribute variable (site) into these bars.

[Looking for bars something like these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF9yy.jpg)